# Php find number of hosts from IP/mask

Tags: php, networking

How can i find the number of hosts from IP/mask (ex: 190.200.22.32/255.255.255.224) ?

I have checked all the functions in : http://php.net/manual/en/ref.network.php

But i'm not able to achieve it.

Please help.

Thanks,
Sash

Comment: @putvande pls check question, thanks

Comment: @AmalMurali pls check question, thanks

Comment: @sash. That is just a link, I don;t see any of YOUR code. So please provide some code that you have tried.

Comment: @putvande you don't understand, if i know which functions to use, why would i ask here?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need PHP to do that. The mask gives you the number of bits that are available for hosts in a subnet. Maximum is 32 in a mask. 255.255.255.0 is 24 bits (each competed octet is 8 bits). So you have 2^(32-24) -2 hosts. So in this case you have 254 hosts.

What you could do in PHP would be something similar to

```
$octets = explode(".",$mask);
$i=0;
 while($octets[$i]==255){
    $i++;
 }
 $interestingOctet=$octets[$i];
 //count the number of bits in the interesting part. 
 $maskbits = ($i+1)*8 + substr_count(decbin($interestingOctet),1);
 echo pow(2,$maskbits)-2; //this is the number of hosts for this subnet mask
```

In order to find the range of all IP you should find the binary representation of the IP address and do a bitwise BOOLEAN AND it with the binary representation of the Subnet mask. This will give you the Subnet Number. Then invert the mask (change all 1 to 0 and all 0 to 1) and do a bitwise BOOLEAN OR with the subnet number (you found in the previous step). The result is the broadcast address. All the IPs available to you are the IP address between the subnet number and the broadcast address. (e.g. subnet number 192.168.1.0 and broadcast address 255.255.255.0 then the range is 192.168.1.1 up until 192.168.1.254).

To get this in PHP you have to do basically what i did with the interesting octet above (without counting the 1s) and then use bitwise operators `http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php` in each respective octet. Hope this helps.

Comment: is it possible to get all the ip's (hosts) from IP/mask (ex: 190.200.22.32/255.255.255.224)

Comment: But this host count involves some invalid real world IP's with .0 and .255 right?

Comment: No. That's why you do the -2. Also the range is form 1 to 254 as I have written. If this solves your question please do not forget to mark as answered.